# what is IV in symetric encryption in mssql

Tags: encryption, sql-server

I found this command for learning details about encryption with symmetric keys in MS-SQL 2014 but this query did not provide the IV. How can I find the IV in my encryption?

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.symmetric_keys;
```

Comment: Are you using column-level encryption?

Comment: yes and my symmetric keys is AES 256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inizialization vector (IV) is randomly generated and added to the metadata of the encrypted result. In particular:

> The format for the encrypted result with metadata follows the following format:
>
> The first 16 bytes of the encrypted result represent the GUID of the symmetric key used to encrypt the data.
>
> The next 4 bytes represent a version number [...]
>
> The next 8 bytes for DES encryption (**16 bytes for AES encryption**) **represent the randomly generated IV**. [...]

Source: Jay Natarajan, Rudi Bruchez, Michael Coles, Scott Shaw, Miguel Cebollero, Pro T-SQL Programmer's Guide.

As such, the initialization vectors (plural) are not stored in sys.symmetric_keys, but in the encrypted data themselves.